# Selecting a checkbox in mySQL DB

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I ran a sql query in an effort to update a column for a specific user who listed bunch of products that were set to expire.

When I look at the phpmyadmin db, all of the products had `end_time` filled with zeros thanks to my wrong sql query shown below.

```
UPDATE my_listing SET end_time='NULL' WHERE user_id='3'
```

What I needed was to check the "Null" checkbox in `end_time`, to ensure unlimited duration, the zeros did the opposite and made all products 'expired'.
How do I set the "Null" checkbox checked without going manually and doing it by hand?

Thanks much!

[image: DB screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkbox of phpmyadmin has no effect on the column value, but only sets if it can be set to NULL. Therefore after having checked it you should simply run again the query like that:

UPDATE my_listing SET end_time=NULL WHERE user_id='3'

without the ' ' around NULL.

Comment: Didn't work, the zeros are back again, the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Have you tried checking if the column is nullable? "SHOW COLUMNS FROM my_listing"

Comment: For whatever strange reason, the first time I ran it, didn't work, after 30 min. I ran it again and it worked just fine... so much for phpmyadmin...

Answer (score 1):

Just run another query, this time setting `end_time` to `NULL` instead of the string `'NULL'`:

```
UPDATE my_listing SET end_time = NULL WHERE user_id = '3'
```

Comment: It didn't work, the "Null" checkbox is not checked, once again zeros showed up across, the listings appeared as 'expired'